# JS - append to the same string in recursive scenario

Tags: javascript, string, recursion, reference, immutability

I read that in JS stings are immutable, and even though the default for JS appears to be "pass by reference", passing the same string around a recursive hierarchy will not append to the same string but rather create copies.

My scenario requires for a single string object to be created once, and passed around in a very deep and long hierarchy of recursive and other functions, so how can I achieve this? I am a C++ guy, and in C++ it is quite easy... just pass by reference and all functions work on the same bit of string.

Comment: could try collapsing the recursion with your own stack (hopefully doesnt overflow ;)

Comment: @amdixon - it is not an option, besides recursion I have object hierarchies which must append to the same string.

Comment: Probably answering your original question would be easier. Why don't you paste the recursive call and then try to convince everyone that there is no way in JS to make it work? Someone will then gladly point out the JS way of doing it.

Comment: You could use an array to store the string parts, and then "join" the result into one array once the recursion is done.

Comment: @amdixon - it is not HTML, but QML, I don't know how applicable jquery is to QML that has a completely different DOM and so forth.

Comment: Try [javascript stringbuilder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12375/JavaScript-StringBuilder)

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate pass by reference for primitive values using a wrapper object. This involves altering your functions to be aware of that:

```
function append(strWrapper,n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return strWrapper;
  } else {
    strWrapper.val += n;
    return append(strWrapper, n-1);
  }
}

console.log(append({ val : '' }, 9).val); // 987654321
```

Of course the wrapper object could turn into a wrapper class if you are so inclined.

*JS does pass by reference only for objects, not for primitive values

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Array/String Objects as they are passed by reference , something like below code to find subsequences i have passed array of string (output) to store all subsequences in  which is passed in every call
`

```
function subsequence( input, output){
    if(input.length==0)
    {
        output[0]="";
        return 1;
    }

    let  smallStr = input.substr(1); 
    let  smallerSeqSize = subsequence(smallStr,output);

    for(let i=0;i<smallerSeqSize;i++){
        output[smallerSeqSize+i] = input[0]+output[i]; 
    }

    

    return 2*smallerSeqSize;
}


 function main(){

    let input = "abc";
    let output = new Array("")

    let sizeOutput = subsequence(input,output);

    console.log(output)

    
}`
```